# How to echo explode array?

Tags: php

**EDIT:** More clear: I want to echo $data as an array.

I have this:

```
$lic = $_GET['lic'];
$locationtodb =  '../../files/';
$licenses = $locationtodb.'filea.txt';
$SearchLicense = $lic;
$pattern = preg_quote($SearchLicense, '/');
$pattern = "/^.*$pattern.*\$/m";
preg_match_all($pattern, $licenses, $matches);
$wholeLine = implode("\n", $matches[0]);
$data = explode(":", $wholeLine);
```

I can use somethings like this to replace strings:

```
$CurrentLine = $lic.':'.'active'.':'.$data[2];
$NewLine = $lic.':'.'suspended'.':'.$data[2];

$new_contents = file_get_contents($licenses);
$new_contents = str_replace($CurrentLine,$NewLine,$new_contents);
file_put_contents($licenses,$new_contents);
```

And it does work !

But if I typed something like:

```
echo $data[2];
```

It give nothing ...

Why?

Thanks.

Comment: do var_dump($data); and you will see exactly why.

Comment: I'm going to guess that `$data2` is either whitespace, so it won't show up, or there isn't a third element, and you're missing an error.

Comment: `array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" }` ?

Comment: Your array just has one element, so you can't access the index 2.

Comment: Then how to do what I want ?

Comment: I don't know what you want to do.

Comment: Use `echo $data[2];` Read the question for more info.

Comment: More clear: I want to echo $data as an array.

Comment: You can't output what isn't there. Make sure your `$data` has the correct values you expect it to have.

Comment: Well `$data` is defined here: `$data = explode(":", $wholeLine);` and [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php#refsect1-function.explode-returnvalues) would return the entire string if the delimiter isn't found in the string, but you got an array with an empty string, which would suggest that `$wholeLine` was already an empty string. And `$wholeLine` is defined here `implode("\n", $matches[0]);` and that means that `$matches[0]` is an empty string here. So you want to start with `$matches[0]` and look at where it comes from, which you don't show us here, and why it is empty.

Comment: @Rizier123 - I added the remaining codes in the question, check now.

Comment: This just follows down the rabbit hole. You need to check what you actually got in your variables and see what you expect and what you actually got in them. And that is something only you can do!

Answer (score 0):

Solution discovered!

```
$licenses = $locationtodb.'filea.txt';
```

Must be:

```
$licenses = file_get_contents($locationtodb.'filea.txt');
```